# LESS: Can you group a CSS selector with a media query?

Tags: css, css-selectors, less, media-queries

I really enjoyed finding out you could create a media query variable that you can easily reuse and makes your code much more readable.

```
@tablet: ~"(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px)";
@media @tablet { ... }
```

I want to know if it's possible to group a media query with a selector. It doesn't appear to work the way I've implemented it, but I thought I'd ask to see if it's even probable.

```
@tablet: ~"(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px)";
body {
  aside { ... }

  &.homepage,
  @media @tablet {
    aside { ... }
  }
}
```

I understand that media queries are different from run-of-the-mill selectors because you have to define your selectors inside of the media query, but is there some voodoo LESS way to accomplish grouping like this?

Comment: How do you expect to have a selector like this:  `body.homepage, @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px)`?  That's not valid CSS.

Comment: I realize that. I don't want to have to duplicate large chunks of CSS that apply to a particular class AND break-point if I can avoid it.

Comment: Your only option is to use a mixin.

Comment: Glad to hear it's not impossible! :)

Can you elaborate or provide an example of how that might work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a 100% certain of the output you are going for, but this LESS only defines the color `red` once, and applies it to both:

```
@tablet: ~"(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px)";
body {
  aside { color: blue }

  &.homepage {
    aside { color: red }
  }

  @media @tablet {
    .homepage;
  }
}
```

Yields this CSS:

```
body aside {
  color: #0000ff;
}
body.homepage aside {
  color: #ff0000;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) {
  body aside {
    color: #ff0000;
  }
}
```