# Referece parent's parent in LESS nest

Tags: less

Is there any way I can reference the  element within a nest of one of it's children?

I have the following:

```
div.chem_stage {
    position: relative;

    html.no-canvas {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Of course this doesn't work, is there a method using LESS to allow me to do this? I could do

```
html.no-canvas {
    .chem_stage {

    }
    .another_element {

    }
    etc...
}
```

But I have lots of elements I need to apply this rule to and I'd rather keep my rules in situ

Edit:

Using ScottS's techqniue, it doesn't seem to mix with @media queries

```
div.chem_stage {
    html.no-canvas &, @media only screen and (max-width : @respChem) {
```

produces

```
html.no-canvas div.chem_stage,
div.chem_stage $media only screen and (max-width : @respChem) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer to Original Question

I believe what you are seeking is the `&` combinator in LESS:

**LESS**

```
div.chem_stage {
    position: relative;

    html.no-canvas & {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
div.chem_stage {
  position: relative;
}
html.no-canvas div.chem_stage {
  display: none;
}
```

For a more detailed discussion of the particular use you refer to, [see my answer to this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537260/less-css-abusing-the-operator-when-nesting), where I label it "End Target Grouping."

### Update for Media Query Addition

Media queries in LESS are temperamental. They do not like to be mixed with regular selectors. [This answer addressed some of those issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843858/less-can-you-group-a-css-selector-with-a-media-query/13844216#13844216), and how you might combine code. However, in your case, probably a mixin is best, as you need to keep them separate and you cannot really use the `html.no-canvas` call as a mixin. So something like this:

**LESS**

```
div.chem_stage {
    position: relative;

    .groupedCode() {
        display: none;
    }

    html.no-canvas & {
        .groupedCode()
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width : @respChem) { 
        .groupedCode()
    }
}
```

**CSS Output** (Assuming `@respChem` is `300px` here)

```
div.chem_stage {
  position: relative;
}
html.no-canvas div.chem_stage {
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  div.chem_stage {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah perfect! I've always used & but never thought to put it after a rule! Thank you!

Comment: Had some issues mixing it with @media queries, I've updated my question

Comment: @GreenGiant: added thoughts regarding `@media`.

Comment: a nice use of mixins for this solution thank you. I presume the mixins scope is limited to that nest, so I could use .no-animation() for my grouped code in multiple nests elsewhere (with different rules).

Comment: @GreenGiant: Yes, if it is defined locally in a nest, it can be redefined in another nest (or you can set one globally to handle any global aspects, and another per nest to modify it locally as needed).